# How do I rewrite this LINQ expression using consistent syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

This one-statement query says neatly "Give me a list of bare filenames for which the file is a ZIP repository containing a certain file structure."

But I use both a .Where() extension method (fluent syntax) and a select query, because anything else I try fails to compile.  If I change  ".Where(file ==> <statement>)" to "where <statement>", I get an error that the anonymous method code does not return a bool, and if I change the "select <clause>" to ".Select(<clause>)", the error is "No select clause is used."

I'm happy with either query or fluent syntax, but I'd like to settle on one or the other.  Can anyone explain why this does not work, and what I would need to do to settle on one consistent syntax?

```
return (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), Globals.CompanyName, ProjectName, FolderName),
                    imageExtension,
                    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(file =>
    {
        try
        {
            string relativePath = ClassFru.Station + "/";   // Inside ZIPs, paths use a single forward slash
            var zip = new ZipFile();
            zip.ZipError += (s, o) => { throw new Exception(); };
            using (zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
            {
                /// <todo>if (zip.Comment != Globals.CompanyName) { return false; }</todo>
                foreach (var fru in this.gFrus)
                {
                    var fruPath = relativePath + fru.Id + '.';
                    if (!(from e in zip where !e.IsDirectory && e.FileName.StartsWith(fruPath) select true).Any()) { return false; }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    })
    select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I think this may be one of those cases where a few `foreach` enumerations are more understandable :)

Comment: The contents of that `Where` almost certainly shouldn't be an anonymous method; that should be a named method so that you can write something like `.Where(DirectoryIsValid)` or something like that.

Comment: The reason you get "No select clause is used" is because you have a `from` as well. Either convert the entire thing to method syntax, or do as Servy said and extract your lambda into a method.

Comment: @KendallFrey That needs to be done *in addition* to my suggestion, it's not an either or.  That change just makes it easier to see the mistake, that's all.

Comment: @Servy Looks like a logical or to me. There is no reason other than readability that you would have to use a concrete method with method syntax.

Comment: @KendallFrey You said in your first comment [something to fix the code] or do as Servy said.  I'm saying that my code is merely a socialistic change and doesn't fix the actual problem.  Your first comment implies it would.

Comment: @Servy I guess I was assuming that "or **use query syntax and** do as Servy said" was implied.

Comment: "This one-statement query says neatly...". I disagree. There is nothing neat about starting with linQ syntax, switching to fluent syntax and then into an anonymous function with a "catch-em-all" try clause and a loop. and then back to linQ. As @Servy suggests, refactor out the anonymous function into a separate named method, where it belongs. Readability is king: you don't need any other reason to do this.

Comment: @DavidArno It's "query syntax" not "linq syntax", fyi.

Comment: @Servy, well spotted. I get used to thinking of it as "proper linq" as I personally prefer it to the fluent approach and so tend to think of it as linq syntax. I must stop that :)

Comment: @DavidArno LINQ is nothing more or less than the set of classes/methods in the "System.Linq" namespace.  Technically query syntax can be used without using LINQ at all, although it almost never is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't have all type you're using in this expression it's quite hard to compile it but I think i should work like that:

```
            return (Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
                Globals.CompanyName, ProjectName, FolderName),
            imageExtension,
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Where(file => {
                try
                {
                    string relativePath = ClassFru.Station + "/"; // Inside ZIPs, paths use a single forward slash
                    var zip = new ZipFile();
                    zip.ZipError += (s, o) => {
                        throw new Exception();
                    };
                    using (zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
                    {
                        /// <todo>if (zip.Comment != Globals.CompanyName) { return false; }</todo>
                        foreach (var fru in this.gFrus)
                        {
                            var fruPath = relativePath + fru.Id + '.';
                            if(zip.Any(e=> !e.IsDirectory && e.FileName.StartsWith(fruPath))
                                    .Any())
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }).Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToArray());
```

Comment: Good answers, all, thank you very much, but I like this best, since it actually gives working concise code without linquistic (ha!) religious warfare.  The original version of the code WAS using a named method, but because the query is part of a large method, it separated implementation from reference by quite a distance.  For me, this is much better, since it says all I want in one place.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing the use of `select` to `Select(file =>` you also need to remove the `from file in` at the start.  Then you'll have remove the use of that query syntax `select` clause.  It was that lone `from` clause that was causing the error you were seeing.  Each `from [...] in` clause needs a matching `select`.

Comment: +1 I don't know why I never noticed before that when I saw .Select) I did not see a from clause.  I have always found query syntax more readable, but I am slowly learning different.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm happy with either query or fluent syntax, but I'd like to settle on one or the other. Can anyone explain why this does not work, and what I would need to do to settle on one consistent syntax?

It's not working very well for you because LINQ was not really made to handle large blocks of complex logic as criteria. LINQ Expression syntax, in particular, makes the assumption that you are going to provide Expressions (not Blocks), so it doesn't directly support multi-line statements.

If you simply remove the `from` portion of your query, you can easily get method syntax to work, as [ISun shows you how to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527311/120955).

On the other hand, your code will be much more understandable and modular if you simply extract your anonymous method out, as @Servy suggested in comments. In that case, you could either decide to say `where FileHasMatchingZipStructure(file)`. or `.Where(FileHasMatchingZipStructure)`, as you like.